# How much LEAPS can lose with deep in-the-money strike price?

Tags: call-options

This is the scenario. The current price of a stock is $100. I buy a **CALL $50 strike that expires in 2 years** contract for $10,000.  An year later the price of the stock drops to $80 and float around that value until 2 years.

What are the possibilities on the day of expiration in 2 years?

- I will lose the $10,000
- I will break even with $10,000
- I will keep some amount like $8000

Comment: The numbers don't make sense. Given a stock price of $100 and a strike of $50, the quoted price of a call would be between about $50 and $100. The amount paid for one contract (100x) would be between about $5,000 and $10,000. The $3,000 is too high to be the quoted call price and too low to be the amount paid.

Comment: I updated the contract price to $10,000.

Comment: What, exactly is your question? Your scenario makes no sense. A $50 strike on a $100 stock would never sell for $100. Do you understand why? I am the down vote. A LEAP can lose all its cost if the stock closes below the strike price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the call position at expiration is 100 x ($80 - $50) = $3,000, so you will lose $7,000.

Note that paying $10,000 for the call is an extreme scenario where the stock has sky-high volatility. You might as well have bought 100 shares of the stock itself for the same amount, and then you would lose only $2,000. It would be pretty shocking, though, for such an extremely volatile stock to move *only* 20%. Bottom line, your example would make more sense if you paid *less than* $10,000 (but more than $5,000) for the call.

Answer (score 1):

If the stock is at $80 when the $50 call expires you'll "get" $30 per share at expiry (either $30 in cash or in stock that you pay $50 for and can hopefully sell for $80 for a $30 profit)

The $100 per share that you paid in premium is a "sunk cost". You do not get any of it back at expiry, so your overall loss for the trade will be $70 per share of $7,000 per contract.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the question after editing are not realistic.  If they were, you could buy stock XYZ  for $100 and sell the $50 covered call for a $100 premium.  That would be a no cost/no risk position with a profit  potential of $50 if XYZ was at or above $50 at expiration and no loss if XYZ went to zero.

Regarding your question, at expiration, your call will expire worthless if the stock is below $50.  If above $50, your call will be worth the stock's price less $50 (intrinsic value).  For example, at $70, your call will be worth $20 for a loss of $80.

Your expiration break even point will be the strike price ($50) plus the cost of the call ($100) or $150.  Above $150 you will make money.

In order to guesstimate the value before expiration, you'll need an option pricing model and you'll have to make a volatility assumption.  There are web sites which offer this.  [Here's one](https://www.optionsprofitcalculator.com/calculator/covered-call.html).